# Optimize query performance for a filter on col_a > col_b

Tags: postgresql, index, postgresql-performance, index-tuning

I have a large table in a PostgreSQL database (~100 columns, millions of rows). My query has no joins but it does have several where clauses. All of the where clauses are covered by appropriate indices except for one which has the form `WHERE table.col_a > table.col_b`. My question is, if I make an index on `table(col_a, col_b)` will that optimize the greater than operation or do I need to do something particular to make this efficient?

---

EDIT: Adding anonymized query / explain / ddl per @frank-heikens comment.

I did notice in reviewing that `col_f` doesn't have an index and I suspect adding it would solve a large part of my problem. That said, I'd still like to know the best way to optimize for `table.col_b < table.col_a`.

If it helps, `col_b` is almost always 0.0 and `col_a` is always positive. My guess would be that this reduces the performance benefit because relatively few rows are filtered by this clause. Any advice on the relative cost/benefit of a multi-column index or expression index would be welcome.

Query:

```
explain(analyze, verbose, buffers, settings)
SELECT id, col_a, col_b, col_c, col_d, col_e
FROM  public.table
WHERE col_f = 'VALUE' AND
      col_g != 'EXCLUDED_VALUE' AND
      col_b < col_a AND
      NOT ((col_h 'EXCLUDED_VALUE_1', 'EXCLUDED_VALUE_2') OR
           col_h IS NULL)) AND
      col_e IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY col_e DESC
LIMIT 5;
```

```
                                                     QUERY PLAN                                                                                                                                                                                              
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=10.61..10.62 rows=1 width=73) (actual time=0.101..0.102 rows=1 loops=1)
   Output: id, col_a, col_b, col_c, col_d, col_e
   Buffers: shared hit=2
   ->  Sort  (cost=10.61..10.62 rows=1 width=73) (actual time=0.100..0.100 rows=1 loops=1)
         Output: id, col_a, col_b, col_c, col_d, col_e
         Sort Key: table.col_e DESC
         Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
         Buffers: shared hit=2
         ->  Seq Scan on public.table  (cost=0.00..10.60 rows=1 width=73) (actual time=0.046..0.083 rows=1 loops=1)
               Output: id, col_a, col_b, col_c, col_d, col_e
               Filter: ((table.col_h IS NOT NULL) AND (table.col_e IS NOT NULL) AND ((table.col_g)::text <> 'EXCLUDED_VALUE'::text) AND (table.col_b < table.col_a) AND ((table.col_h)::text <> ALL ('{EXCLUDED_VALUE_1,EXCLUDED_VALUE_2}'::text[])) AND ((table.col_f)::text = 'VALUE'::text))
               Rows Removed by Filter: 10
               Buffers: shared hit=2
 Planning Time: 0.467 ms
 Execution Time: 0.149 ms
(15 rows)
```

DDL:

```
-- Dumped from database version 14.10 (Homebrew)

CREATE TABLE public.table (
    id uuid DEFAULT gen_random_uuid() NOT NULL,
    col_a double precision,
    col_b double precision,
    col_c boolean,
    col_d character varying,
    col_e timestamp(6) without time zone,
    col_f character varying,
    col_g character varying,
    col_h character varying,
    -- columns not referenced in the query have been elided
);

ALTER TABLE ONLY public.table
    ADD CONSTRAINT table_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id);

CREATE INDEX index_table_on_col_e ON public.table USING btree (col_e);
CREATE INDEX index_table_on_col_g ON public.table USING btree (col_g);
CREATE INDEX index_table_on_col_h ON public.table USING btree (col_h);

-- indexes for columns not referenced in the query have been elided
```

Comment: Could you please share the result from `explain(analyze, verbose, buffers, settings)` for your SQL statement, the statement itself and the DDL for all tables and indexes involved? All in plain text, as an update of your original question.

Comment: `Execution Time: 0.149 ms`, what kind of performance do you expect when sub-millisecond performance is not good enough? Your table is also nearly empty, is that your production table?

Comment: If you still need to optimize that query, please start a *new question* with [information as instructed](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3299/3684) and no focus on the dead end with non-selective `cola > colb`. Leave this one as is for public interest on possible application of a partial index.

Comment: @FrankHeikens this was not run against production data. It took too long in production. The explain was run in my development environment which has far less data.

Comment: Performance testing on an empty database, while having issues on a (large?) production database, doesn't make sense. The query planner uses statistics from this data, without data it doesn't have any statistics, falls back to default behavior and would still be fast because the database is nearly empty. Always test on a comparable data set. Or even better, get the query plans from your production database.

Comment: Composite indexes might help if you have selective enough column combination, like
CREATE INDEX index_table_on_col_f_h ON public.table USING btree (col_f,col_h)

Answer (score 4):

> If it helps, `col_b` is almost always 0.0 and `col_a` is always
> positive. My guess would be that this reduces the performance benefit
> because relatively few rows are filtered by this clause.

In this case, index support will **not** help queries with `WHERE col_a > col_b` at all. A [**partial index**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-partial.html) like has been suggested is the best option for a *selective* filter like that. But almost all rows pass your filter, that partial index would do more harm than good. Don't create a partial index or Postgres might use it.

```
CREATE INDEX ... WHERE cola > colb;
```

Postgres *should* not use it for your query, but still might based on misleading estimates and unhelpful column statistics. And other types of indexes will not help at all. The manual about [**extended statistics**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/planner-stats.html#PLANNER-STATS-EXTENDED):

> Regular statistics, because of their per-individual-column nature, cannot capture any knowledge about cross-column correlation.

Sadly, extended statistics for [**functional dependencies**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/planner-stats.html#PLANNER-STATS-EXTENDED-FUNCTIONAL-DEPS) cannot currently help either. The manual on [limitations of functional dependencies](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/planner-stats.html#PLANNER-STATS-EXTENDED-FUNCTIONAL-DEPS-LIMITS):

> Functional dependencies are currently only applied when considering
> simple equality conditions that compare columns to constant values,
> and `IN` clauses with constant values.

So this is a dead end.

#### Solution

Unknown.

Certainly don't add an index for `WHERE cola > colb`. Indexes are for *selective* criteria.

There are probably other ways to optimize. But it's impossible to tell from your explain plan on a dummy table with barely any rows. We would need to know what's actually selective. Provide information as instructed here:

- [Asking query performance questions](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3299/3684)

Start with a valid query. The one you show has a syntax error. Probably missing `IN`.

Comment: Thanks, this has been informative. The real solution is probably to add an index for col_f as mentioned in my edit above and we're looking into solving this problem with a different architecture that uses more caching at this point anyway because we are nervous about the impact of additional indices on writes.

Answer (score 3):

No, but you can add a `WHERE` clause to the index:

```
CREATE INDEX ... WHERE cola > colb;
```